# Android listview showing only last element

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

i created custom listview with text and two buttons, i set up arraylist and adapter but my listview is showing every element as last, for ex. if i add 3 elements: "text1","text2","text3" my listview shows "text3", "text3" "text3" and i dont have any idea why.

```
  private ListView lista;
  private List<Piosenka> listaPiosenek;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lista.setClickable(true);             
}

 public void update_listy() throws MalformedURLException, IOException
 {
  final List<Piosenka> listaPiosenek = new ArrayList<Piosenka>();

    listaPiosenek.add(new Piosenka("text1"));  
    listaPiosenek.add(new Piosenka("text2"));  
    listaPiosenek.add(new Piosenka("text3"));

  PiosenkaAdapter adapter = new PiosenkaAdapter(this, listaPiosenek);

  lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long index)              
{
          System.out.println("sadsfsf");
      }
  });

  lista.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Edit: PiosenkaAdapter code

```
public class PiosenkaAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {
 private Context context;

    private List<Piosenka> listapiosenek;

    public PiosenkaAdapter(Context context, List<Piosenka> listapiosenek) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listapiosenek = listapiosenek;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return listapiosenek.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listapiosenek.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        Piosenka element = listapiosenek.get(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_element, null);
        }
        TextView tvTytul = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTytul);
        tvTytul.setText(Piosenka.getTytul());

        Button btnPobierz = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnPobierz);
        btnPobierz.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        btnPobierz.setFocusable(false);

        btnPobierz.setTag(element);
        Button btnPlay = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        btnPlay.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        btnPlay.setFocusable(false);
        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnPlay.setTag(element);

        // btnRemove.setId(position);


        return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
         switch(view.getId()){  
         case R.id.btnPobierz:  
             Piosenka entry = (Piosenka) view.getTag();
             listapiosenek.remove(entry);
             notifyDataSetChanged();
             break;
         case R.id.btnPlay:
             entry = (Piosenka) view.getTag();
             listapiosenek.remove(entry);
             notifyDataSetChanged();
             break;
    }
    }
```

}

Comment: Please post PiosenkaAdapter's code, the error is most likely there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
lista.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Can you paste you PiosenkaAdapter's code?

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to send notifyDataSetChanged() when the list is created before the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your language, but the `Piosenka` variable is fetched correctly in getView()

```
Piosenka element = listapiosenek.get(position);
```

But this looks strange to me

```
TextView tvTytul = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTytul);
tvTytul.setText(Piosenka.getTytul());
```

`Piosenka.getTytul()` looks to me as a static method call, where you should do a regular method call to `element.getTytul()` instead.